# How to do multiselect option using php laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am creating vehicle edit form in php using laravel 5.2 framework, and fetching values from the mysql database to the form. using two tables data in form. In the form, am giving one drop down list for group membership. The data in that drop down list is fetching from the databse. I need to get that drop down list as multi select drop down list. Means in vehicle edit form we can assign that particular vehicle to more than one group. How can i do this multi select in php using laravel 5.2

my vehicle edit (view page) giving below

```
   @extends('app')

@section('content')
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
                <li class="active">View/Edit Vehicle</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-heading">View/Edit Vehicle Information</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('vehicle/update/') }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
@foreach($devices as $device)
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vehicle ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deviceID" value="{{ ($device->deviceID)}}">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Creation date</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="creationTime" value="{{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',($device->creationTime))}}">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!--<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Server ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userID" value="" placeholder="Enter User ID">

                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Unique ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="uniqueID" value="{{ ($device->uniqueID)}}" placeholder="Enter Unique ID">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Active</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ ($device->isActive) }}" name="isActive" >
                                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                            <option value="0">No</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vehicle Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ ($device->description) }}" placeholder="Enter the description">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Short Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="displayName" value="{{ ($device->displayName) }}" placeholder="Enter Display Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Vehicle ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vehicleID" value="{{ ($device->vehicleID) }}" placeholder="Enter Vehicle ID">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">License Plate</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="licensePlate" value="{{ ($device->licensePlate) }}" placeholder="Enter license Plate">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">License Expiration</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="licenseExpire" value="{{ ($device->licenseExpire) }}" placeholder="Enter license Expire Date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Equipment Type</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="equipmentType" value="{{ ($device->equipmentType) }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Equipment Status</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ ($device->equipmentStatus) }}" name="equipmentStatus" >
                                            <option>Unspecified</option>
                                            <option value="inservice">In Service</option>
                                            <option value="rented">Rented</option>
                                            <option value="pending">Pending</option>
                                            <option value="completed">Completed</option>
                                            <option value="available">Available</option>
                                            <option value="unavailable">Unavailable</option>
                                            <option value="repair">Repair</option>
                                            <option value="retired">Retired</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">IMEI/EDN Number</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="imeiNumber" value="{{ ($device->imeiNumber) }}" placeholder="Enter IMEI/EDN Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Serial Number</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="serialNumber" value="{{ ($device->serialNumber) }}" placeholder="Enter Serial Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <!--    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Data Key</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">SIM Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="simPhoneNumber" value="{{ ($device->simPhoneNumber) }}" placeholder="Enter SIM Phone Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">SMS Email Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="smsEmail" value="{{ ($device->smsEmail) }}" placeholder="Enter SMS E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            <!--    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Group Pushpin ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Map Route Color</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ ($device->displayColor) }}" name="displayColor" >
                                            <option>Default</option>
                                            <option value="#000000">Black</option>
                                            <option value="#a52a2a">Brown</option>
                                            <option value="#dd0000">Red</option>
                                            <option value="#b37400">Orange</option>
                                            <option value="#008f00">Green</option>
                                            <option value="#0000ee">Blue</option>
                                            <option value="#9400d3">Purple</option>
                                            <option value="#505050">Grey</option>
                                            <option value="#00b3b3">Cyan</option>
                                            <option value="#ff1493">Pink</option>
                                            <option value="none">None</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>




                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fuel Capacity</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fuelCapacity" value="{{ ($device->fuelCapacity) }}" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Driver ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="driverID" value="{{ ($device->driverID) }}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                         <!--       <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Reported Odometer</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Reported Engine Hours</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>  -->

                                    <div class="form-group">

                                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Group Membership</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('groupID') }}" name="groupID" >
                                                @foreach( $grouplist as $group)
                                                    @if ($group->groupID == old('description'))
                                                        <option value="{{ $group->groupID }}" selected[]>{{ $group->groupID." ".'['.$group->description.']' }}</option>
                                                    @else
                                                        <option value="{{ $group->groupID }}" >{{ $group->groupID." ".'['.$group->description.']' }}</option>
                                                    @endif
                                                @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>




                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                            Update
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
@endforeach
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and the controller page is

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    try {
        //Find the vehicle object from model if it exists
        $grouplist = Map::select('groupID','description')->get();


        $devices = DB::table('device')->where('deviceID', '=', $id)->get();

        //Redirect to edit vehicle form with the user info found above.
        return view('vehicle.add')->with(['devices'=>$devices,'grouplist'=>$grouplist]);
       // return view('vehicle.add')->with('devices', $devices)->with('grouplist',$grouplist);


    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $err) {
        //redirect to your error page
    }
}
```

Anyone Please help me to do this. Responses are appreciable.

Comment: add `multiple` in select tag to do the multi select for ex. `<select class="form-control" value="{{ old('groupID') }}" name="groupID" multiple>` not in option.

Comment: ohk,, let me try..

Comment: yeah i did, now am getting scroll down list instead of drop down. But there is no option for selecting multiple group..

Comment: ohk then go to here .. https://select2.github.io/examples.html. for finding more multiple select dropdowns.

Comment: @Dhaval Purohit, i went through that website. They are using hard coded drop down list for multi select option. I didn't get clear idea for my problem.

Comment: the drop down are not hard coded you can use it same way which you are using now. just add the script and call the select function and everything works fine.

Comment: i tried in the same way. but still am getting scroll down list only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123753/discussion-between-dhaval-purohit-and-rahul-vp).

Answer (score 0):

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="group[]" id="group">
@foreach($grouplist as $aKey => $group)
    @foreach($grouplist->sports as $aItemKey => $grouplist)
        <option value="{{$aKey}}" @if($aKey == $aItegrouplistmKey)selected="selected"@endif>{{$group}}</option>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
</select
```

Comment: why you are using two foreach??